# Convert MySQL decimal values with a format that varies by value

Tags: mysql

I need to convert `DECIMAL` field to a `CHAR` representation, with a format that varies by the field's value.

Values are from a vendor's database; they will be:

- > 0
- values < 1 will be in tenths (e.g. 0.20)
- values >= 1 will be integer values express as a decimal (e.g. 100.00)

Examples:

- values < 1: `0.10, 0.20` to `.1, .2`
- values >=1: `4101.00, 95.00` to `4101, 95`
- no commas if values > 999

Current approach:

```
CASE
    WHEN id<1 THEN Cast(Round(item,1) AS Char)
    ELSE Cast(Round(item,0) AS Char)
END item
```

** edit **

Second approach:

```
Trim(TRAILING '.' FROM Trim(BOTH '0' FROM Cast(item AS Char))) Item
```

Is there a more succinct way to do this?

Comment: If you're only concerned about the string's appearance, you could probably TRIM off trailing '0's. ([link to docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_trim))

Comment: If you want to play golf, you can replace `CASE`, with `IF` and `Cast(item AS Char)` with `Concat('', item)`.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Your two options aren't equivalent to each other: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f7301/1 . I doubt someone can help you if you don't share your full intentions.